# Get data from table using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a `Emptbl` in which I have `EmpType` Column.

In EmpType I have following data for example :

```
E0123 
M0123
E1245
E4578
M1245
E0478
M4789
E4762
```

Now I want to get only those emp data which have same `EmpType` for example below data:

```
E0123
M0123
E1245
M1245
```

And want to show this data as group by as `0123` and `1245`

So how to get above data? I use `UNION` but it does not get valida data.

Thanks

Comment: Will it always be a 4 digit numeric part?

Comment: No It will be any digit

Comment: There are no duplicates in your sample data.

Comment: Can you explicitly show what the desired output is, e.g. column and row values?

Comment: And what about the letter part? Limited to M and E, or can be different also?

Comment: Hi @Tim Schmelter : Yes I have no duplicate data but in EmpType I have E013 and M0123 So I want get this data as duplicate

Comment: @openshac : I want to get column EmpType in which data like E0123,M0123

Comment: @shree.pat18 M and E are fixed

Comment: @Hitesh: Check my answer updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select A.*
    From EmpTbl A
        Inner Join
    EmpTbl B
        On  SubString(A.EmpType, 2, 4) = SubString(B.EmpType, 2, 4) And
        SubString(A.EmpType, 1, 1) <> SubString(B.EmpType , 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select substring(emptype, 2, len(emptype))
from emptbl
group by substring(emptype, 2, len(emptype))
having count(*) > 1
```

The hard-coded 2 is based on your sample data. If instead you had an arbitrary number of letters before the numeric part, e.g. 'ABCDEFG0123', you could use `patindex` to get the starting index for your substring like so;

```
select substring(emptype, patindex('%[0-9]%',emptype), len(emptype)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with CTE as (Select Name,SUBSTRING(Name,2,5) as Number, ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (PARTITION By SUBSTRING(Name,2,5) ORDER BY Name) AS Row
from #Temp)

Select Temp.Name
From CTE C
     Cross Apply (Select Name FRom CTE T Where T.Number=C.Number) as Temp
Where C.Row>1
```

Here is the [fiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1231/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 4 id from
(
select id,rn=row_number()over(partition by right(id,3) order by right(id,3)) from #t
)x
```

[SEE IT LIVE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17529)

Comment: Why you select top 4?

Answer (score 0):

This is the smallest query that works:

```
select substr(a.emptype, 2) num
join emptbl a
join emptbl b on substr(a.emptype, 2) = substr(b.emptype, 2)
and a.emptype != b.emptype
```